# How to launch protractor tests from remote jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor

I am unable to launch my protractor test from remote jenkins.
I am able to launch the test if the jenkins is installed in my local.
I am not sure if it is because of the direct connect. i also tried to launch the protractor test through selenium webdriver but couldnt make it. please help on this.

The error i am getting is

```
*[16:06:14] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:06:14] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:16:15] E/launcher - session not created
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
[16:16:15] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\home\Administrator\workspace\BlueNet_Automation\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[16:16:15] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE*
```

my config.ts file is

```
*export let config: Config = {
    // The address of a running selenium server.
   //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
   directConnect:true,
   framework:'custom',
   frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
   //allScriptsTimeout: 30000,
  
    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome'
    },
  
    // Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
    // to protractor (in this example conf.js).
    // They may include glob patterns.
    specs: ['../features/MasterEdit.feature'],
    cucumberOpts: {
        // require step definitions
        //tags:"@SmokeTesting",
        format:'json:./cucumberreport.json',
       
        
        require: [
          './stepDefinitions/*.js', // accepts a glob,
        
        ]
      },
      onComplete: () =>{
        var options = {
          theme: 'bootstrap',
          jsonFile: './cucumberreport.json',
          output: './cucumber_report.html',
          reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
          launchReport: true,
          metadata: {
              "App Version":"0.3.2",
              "Test Environment": "STAGING",
              "Browser": "Chrome  54.0.2840.98",
              "Platform": "Windows 10",
              "Parallel": "Scenarios",
              "Executed": "Remote"
          }
      };
   
      reporter.generate(options);
      }*
```

Comment: your chrome driver , chrome and protractor scripts are in the server  itself ?

Comment: best way is to git clone all your script to the jenkins agent and then run it . so that it works same as local

Comment: Yes. Thanks. i am doing that way